# How to automatically set properties on view model with StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I have  an interface ITranslateStuff and a static class and method with a generic parameter that is constrained (where class, ITranslateStuff, new()).

```
string translation = Translator.TranslateStuff<ITranslateStuff>();
```

Depending on which implementation of ITranslateStuff that I pass the method returns a different string.

I have ViewModels with a lot of different properties wich returns implementations of ITranslateStuff, for example:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public string OtherStuff {get; set; }
    public string TranslateStuffExample1 Translations { get; set; }
    public ExampleViewModel2 SubModel {get; set; }
}

public class ExampleViewModel2
{
    public string MoreStuff { get; set; }
    public string TranslateStuffExample2 Translations { get; set; }
}
```

where both DoStuffExample1 and DoStuffExample2 implements ITranslateStuff.

I'm currently populating all theese properties with code like this:

```
model.Translations = Translator.TranslateStuff<TranslateStuffExample1>();

model.SubModel.Translations = Translator.TranslateStuff<TranslateStuffExample2>();
```

In the project we use StructureMap. I want to avoid setting all the properties on my view model manually with the same static method call. I have an ActionFilter where I set common properties on my view model, and was thinking I want to do this in an action filter as well.

I've tried finding something in StructureMap that can do this for me.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If I understand true your problem, you should look at this http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/19/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas/

Comment: This didn't work out. I've accepted Waylons answer. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use 'setter injection'.

http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm#section4

Comment: At the moment I'm hard coding the dependencies everywhere. The SetterInjection sounds like the solution. I'll try it out. Thank you!